# How to set priority for element match in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which matches `cat, os, device, country` from database.

I want to get best match as:

> If all `cat, os, device, country` matches: Rank 1
>
> If any 3 of them matches : Rank 2
>
> If any 2 of them matches : Rank 3
>
> If any 1 of them matches : Rank 4
>
> If none of them matches : Rank 5

How do I set priority as mentioned above in MySQL?

The query for which I am tying to set priority is as below:

```
SELECT id, uid, url, rel, title, text, cat, os, device, country, adult, pro, status FROM ads 
WHERE status = 1 
AND type = 0 
AND budget > 0.01 
AND adult = '$adult' 
-- If This Conditions match Rank it 1st
AND (((cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device LIKE '%$device%')
OR   (cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country = 0 AND os = 0 AND device = 0)
OR   (cat = 0 AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os = 0 AND device = 0)
OR   (cat = 0 AND country = 0 AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device = 0)
OR   (cat = 0 AND country = 0 AND os = 0 AND device LIKE '%$device%'))

-- If This Conditions match Rank it 2nd
OR   ((cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os = 0 AND device = 0)
OR    (cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country = 0 AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device = 0)
OR    (cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country = 0 AND os = 0 AND device LIKE '%$device%')
OR    (cat = 0 AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device = 0)
OR    (cat = 0 AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os = 0 AND device LIKE '%$device%')
OR    (cat = 0 AND country = 0 AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device LIKE '%$device%'))

-- If This Conditions match Rank it 3rd
OR   ((cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device = 0)
OR    (cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os = 0 AND device LIKE '%$device%')
OR    (cat LIKE '%$cat%' AND country = 0 AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device LIKE '%$device%')
OR    (cat = 0 AND country LIKE '%$code%' AND os LIKE '%$os%' AND device LIKE '%$device%'))

-- If This Conditions match Rank it 4th
OR   (cat = 0 AND country = 0 AND os = 0 AND device = 0))
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same conditions to generate a column like this:

```
select id, uid, url, rel, title, text, cat, os, device, country, adult, pro, status, if(cat = 0 AND country = 0 AND os = 0 AND device = 0, 4, if(<conditions for rank 3>, 3, if(<conditions for rank 2>, 2, 1))) as rank FROM ads ...
```

Hope you got the idea.